# Does a single-entry visa allow you to do a long transit in Schengen countries then leave to the country that issued the visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

If I have a single entry visa to France can I plan my trip as follows: I will do a transit for 23 hrs in Greece, then continue my trip the second day to Nice, Cannes, Paris, then to Amsterdam, leave from airport to have another transit for one night in Rome then back home?!

Comment: This is not really an answer, but as long as you don't attempt to leave the transit area at the airport, I think that's fine, because essentially you won't be entering the countries in which you transit. But you have to remain in there, otherwise, you have to go through migrations. Now, I'm not entirely sure about that because I do remember doing immigration into the Schengen area at the first touch, so, if I go Wherever->Spain->Germany, I would do immigration at Spain and then nobody would ask me for the passport again.

Comment: @Pablo Sorry but your "answer" is incorrect. Greece is part of the Schengen zone so the asker doesn't need to stay in the transit zone in Greece. They enter Schengen in Greece and don't leave again until they leave Rome. This is one of the reasons that answers shouldn't be posted as comments: an incorrect answer can be voted down but an incorrect comment can't.

Comment: Well, the reason I posted in comments is that I wasn't totally sure as I had conflicting experiences. Transiting through the Schegen area as far as I know doesn't require a visa, but I did mention that the entry happens at the first Schengen contact in my comment.

Comment: @Pablo The asker isn't transiting in Schengen: they're travelling _to_ the Schengen area, then travelling within it, then leaving it. If you're not sure enough to post an answer, then don't post an answer -- anywhere. Comments are for requesting clarifications of the question, not for posting maybe-answers that aren't of high enough quality to go in the answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single-entry Schengen visa allows you to enter the Schengen area once.

This is exactly what you're doing, so you're fine.  Don't think in terms of entering and leaving countries: think of the Schengen area as a whole.  You're entering the area once, in Greece.  You're then travelling within it (France, Netherlands, Italy) and then you leave to go home.  It doesn't matter that you're going to leave Greece (and France and the Netherlands) because you're not leaving the Schengen area.

Since you're supposed to get the visa from the country where you'll be spending the largest part of your stay, the immigration officials in Greece might want to see hotel bookings, plane/train tickets, etc., to prove that you'll be in France for longer than any of the other countries you're visiting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. "Single entry" means you can enter the Schengen area once, as Greece, France, The Netherlands and Italy are all parts of Schengen your itinerary would only mean one entry into Schengen.

You'll go through immigration in Greece, where you'll show your visa - be prepared to document that France is the main destination of your trip, so that your visa is obtained rightfully - and then you'll travel within Schengen, for those trips you'll probably not have to show neither visa nor passport.